# Autosaving record on multiple unsaved belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a three-model setup like this in Rails 5 (so the `belongs_to` are all **not optional**):

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order # in the migration: t.references :order, null: false
  belongs_to :parcel # in the migration: t.references :parcel, null: false
end

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :parcels
end

class Parcel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :line_items
end
```

the following test fails:

```
class AutosaveAllTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_with_autosave
    order = Order.new()
    order.line_items.build()
    order.parcels.build(line_items: order.line_items)
    order.save!
    assert(order.parcels.count == 1)
    assert(order.line_items.count == 1)
    assert(parcel.line_items.count == 1)
  end
end
```

`order.save!` raises an SQL error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: NOT NULL constraint failed: 
parcels.order_id: INSERT INTO "parcels" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)
```

Is this a bug or am I doing things very wrongly? I'm currently working around this problem, and have also considered a `has_many :through` relation to solve it, but in a perfect world I would love to have the above working.